# generating a rdlc report , the report is generated but old report is being displayed in iframe with consol having a warning

Tags: google-chrome, report, rdlc

Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/pdf: "http://localhost:36571/Notifications/report.pdf".

when the report is opened in incognito its showing the new report but in iframe same old report get displayed

Answer (score 0):

try to use examples from this web-site in your code.

[PDFobject](https://pdfobject.com/static.html)

this is a classic one:
if you can load http://localhost:36571/Notifications/report.pdf
then write like this:

```
<iframe src="./Notifications/report.pdf"  title="title">
   <a href="./Notifications/report.pdf"> ... </a>
</iframe>
```